# "Потому что" и кривое предложение

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

*Контекст: Я не обратил на это внимания.*

**"Для меня потому что это совершенно несущественный фактор".**

Как в таком предложении расставляются знаки?

Могут ли они тут отсутствовать?

Для меня() - смысл теряется при такой расстановке знаков.

Для меня()потому что() - опять не улавливаю смысла.

Без знаков смысл мне понятен...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разговорных конструкциях с "обратными" структурами знаки препинания обычно не ставятся.

Сравните с конструкциями, в которых главное предложение внутри придаточного:

*Он не скажу чтобы был симпатичен*.

*Без него не знаю что бы делал*.

А в "Для меня потому что это совершенно несущественный фактор" всего лишь перестановка внутри придаточного. Никакие знаки не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Да и не нужны знаки. Если бы не было парцелляции, то запятую перед придаточным поставили бы. (Я так понимаю, что вы видите "потому что" и думаете, что знак нужен). А инверсия носит разговорный характер (сами говорите, что предложение "кривое"), никаких знаков, на мой взгляд,  не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве версии:

Исходный вариант (с обозначением интонации): Я не обратил на это внимания. Потому что для менЯ (пз) это совершенно несущЕственный фактор (небольшая пауза на месте перелома интонации знаком препинания не обозначается).

При инверсии логическое ударение падает на местоимение: Для менЯ потому что (ПЗ) это совершенно несущЕственный фактор (увеличенная пауза).

В разговорной речи такой вариант достаточно выразителен, но на письме его передать трудно (можно поставить тире, можно ничего не ставить). В любом случае правильное прочтение предложения определяется ТОЛЬКО ПО КОНТЕКСТУ.

Для меня потому что - это совершенно несущественный фактор.